# Pass gdb variable to a shell command excuted from gdb

Tags: bash, shell, android-ndk, gdb, ndk-gdb

I want to execute a shell command from gdb, this shell command needs an argument, and this argument is a gdb variable. How to make gdb interpret this variable before passing the command  and argument to the shell interpreter ?

For example, in a gdb prompt:

```
(gdb) set $my_arg = 2
(gdb) shell echo $my_arg
```

I would like this to print `2` on `stdout`, but actually it does print a blank line.

Edit: I'm using ndk-gdb, which doesn't support python scripting.

Comment: Have you tried shell "echo $my_arg" or 'echo $my_arg' (I'm a noob to gdb, it's just a guess)

Comment: Yes I did. It does not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a new version of gdb, you can use "eval":

```
(gdb) set $val = 2
(gdb) eval "shell echo %d", $val
2
```

If you have an older version of gdb, then the best you can do is use "set logging" to write things to a file, then use shell utilities like sed to rewrite the file into the form you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! It works on the version of gdb shipped with the android ndk r8 releases.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in lldb?

Answer (score 6):

**Update** This answer is not suitable for ndk-gdb. only for gdb.

It seems that printing a convenience variable in the shell command is not supported directly. However you can use gdb python to achieve it:

```
(gdb) set $my_arg = 2
(gdb) python gdb.execute("shell echo " + str(gdb.parse_and_eval("$my_arg")))
2
(gdb)
```

Comment: Thank you! It does work with a standard version of gdb. Unfortunately I am working with the ndk-gdb (ie a version of gdb provided with the android ndk) and python scripting is not supported in that copy of gdb. I will edit my question to add this detail.